# mahout: command not found

Tags: command, mahout

I am following Mahout cookbook and while running this query :

```
mahout seqdirectory -i $WORK_DIR/original -o $WORK_DIR/sequencesfiles
```

I am getting an error

> mahout: command not found.

I am a beginner in mahout .Kindly help in solving this error.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that the Mahout executable is not in your PATH. I find the easiest way to solve this to be the following:

- set the `MAHOUT_HOME` environment variable. E.g: from the terminal, type `export MAHOUT_HOME=<your Mahout home dir>`. This is required in other use cases and it's generally a good idea to set it.
- Now you can execute the command as `$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout ...`, but we can do better.
- Add the Mahout executable's dir to your PATH, e.g: `export PATH=$PATH:$MAHOUT_HOME/bin`. Now the mahout executable will be available from the command line as simply `mahout`.
- And lastly, to avoid having to remember to do this at the beginning of every terminal session, update your `.bashrc` file to load these settings automatically. E.g: `vi ~/.bashrc` to enter `vi` and start editing your `.bashrc` file.

  - type "i" to enter "insert mode"
  - add the `export MAHOUT_HOME=<your Mahout home dir>` line
  - add the `export PATH=$PATH:$MAHOUT_HOME/bin` line
  - hit the Esc key to exit "insert mode"
  - type "ZZ" to save and quit vi

Answer (score 0):

Your mahout is not found try running mahout from bin directory using following syntax

```
./mahout seqdirectory -i $WORK_DIR/original -o $WORK_DIR/sequencesfiles
```